# Most used media queries for smarthphones and tablets?

Tags: css, mobile, tablet, media-queries

Right now, I'm using this one for **tablets**:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
}
```

and this one for **smarthphones**:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
}
```

I want to keep it simple and use only two.
What are the most used media queries for smarthphone and tablet?

Comment: See the info on [natural breakpoints here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20350990/123033).

Answer (score 0):

I would use for mobile devices:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px)
```

AND
for tablets:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
```

Didn't see the date posted...a little out of date.